# How do i transform subfolders request to params

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using Java server, and I need the sub-folders in the request to act like parameters.

example:

myhost/p/a/1

and I need the server to "understand" it like that:

myhost/p?a=1

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Koby

Comment: Do you only have one parameter?

Comment: Yes for the moment. Is that a big difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: spring 3 mvc @RequestMapping tag can extract path values from uri

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)  
 public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {  
   Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);  
      model.addAttribute("owner", owner);  
      return "displayOwner";   
    }
```

2: use UrlRewiter: http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/. This can extract path parameters using regexp.

```
<rule>  
    <from>^/image/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html\??(.*)?$</from>  
    <to>/image.html?imagecode=$1&amp;$2</to>  
 </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter -- in that filter `getServletPath()` then parse the path and forward the request to appropriate controller/servlet

---

Create a filter at say path `/files/*` [see here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html),

In this filter add the logic that gets you the whole path after base URL -- i.e. your servlet path [see here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29)

You parse this path by splitting using `"/"` and then pass the array as the parameter to the servlet that want to use this path. [see here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) for forwarding the request